# How to make related entity's id(auto-incremented) to be inserted when using one to one relationship in spring-data-jdbc?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I have two tables, these are profile_info and user_Info.
Database ER-diagram

[image: ER-Diagram]

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_info` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userLogin` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userPassword` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userType` enum('user','administrator') DEFAULT NULL,
  `userEmail` varchar(320) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userEmail` (`userEmail`)
);
CREATE TABLE `profile_info` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `userRegistrationDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `userFirstName` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userSurName` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountBalance` double DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userUniqueId` (`userId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkUserId` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user_info` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `chk_accountBalance` CHECK ((`accountBalance` >= 0))
);
```

So I have one to one relationship(one profile is related only to one user)

Here are my entities :

User :

```
@Table("user_info")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Persistable<Integer> {
    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column("userLogin")
    private String userLogin;
    @Column("userPassword")
    private String userPassword;
    @Column("userType")
    private String userType;
    @Column("userEmail")
    private String userEmail;
    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id==null;
    }
}
```

Profile :

```
@Table("profile_info")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Profile implements Persistable<Integer> {
    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column("userRegistrationDate")
    private LocalDateTime userRegistrationDate;
    @Column("userFirstName")
    private String userFirstName;
    @Column("userSurName")
    private String userSurName;
    @Column("accountBalance")
    private double accountBalance;
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "id")
    private User user;
    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id==null;
    }
}
```

I use standard repositories as CRUDRepository
UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Long> {
}
```

ProfileRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<Profile,Integer> {
}
```

And I have that spring config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories("com.example.testrepositories.repository")
public class ApplicationConfig extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource managerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        managerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        managerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdatabase");
        managerDataSource.setUsername("Bruce");
        managerDataSource.setPassword("givanchy");
        return managerDataSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }
}
```

Main method where I test my repositories:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
        ProfileRepository repository = context.getBean("profileRepository",ProfileRepository.class);
        User user = new User(null,"TestLogin","testPassword","user","eeed");
        Profile profile = new Profile(null, LocalDateTime.now(),"fff","sss",250.0,user);
        Profile savedProfile = repository.save(profile);
        System.out.println(savedProfile.getId());
        System.out.println(savedProfile.getUser().getId());
    }
```

output is :

[image]

In database after these actions I have following:

[image: UserInfo]

User info was inserted as it should

But in profile userId wasn't inserted, should it work like that?

[image]

**EDIT**

I changed root entity from Profile to User and it has worked well

User Entity:

```
@Table("user_info")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Persistable<Integer>{
    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column("userLogin")
    private String userLogin;
    @Column("userPassword")
    private String userPassword;
    @Column("userType")
    private String userType;
    @Column("userEmail")
    private String userEmail;
    @MappedCollection(keyColumn = "id",idColumn = "userId")
    private Profile profile;
    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id==null;
    }
}
```

Profile Enity:

```
@Table("profile_info")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Profile  implements Persistable<Integer>{
    @Id
    @Column("id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column("userRegistrationDate")
    private LocalDateTime userRegistrationDate;
    @Column("userFirstName")
    private String userFirstName;
    @Column("userSurName")
    private String userSurName;
    @Column("accountBalance")
    private double accountBalance;
    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id==null;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using JPA annotations instead of `@MappedCollection`?

Comment: @GovindaSakhare I'm using spring-data-jdbc not jpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the use of a one-to-one relationship is wrong. According to your  ER diagram there can be multiple `Profile` rows for each `User`. If that is the case and `Profile` is an aggregate (root), `user_info` is an aggregate root as well. The same is suggested by having a repository for both entities.

We therefore deal with references between aggregates which should be represented by the id only, not object references. That means you should make the `Profile.user` and `Integer` or `AggregateReference<Integer>` and set it to the value of `User.id` after the `User` has been saved.

Some other notes:
`MappedCollection` is not relevant for simple references.
When `A` reference `B` the foreign key in the database goes in the opposite direction. So if `Profile` and `User` actually do have a one to one relationship, `User` should be the aggregate root.

For more background on all this see https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates

Comment: I set User as aggregate root as you said and It worked

Comment: does JdbcRepositoryFactory support Query by example?